# composer.json for just core

Tags: 8

How do I get just Drupal 8 core using [drupal-composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)?

This would be very useful for core development and starting a new project without any assumption.

Comment: You can use `composer require drupal/core` to have composer fetch Drupal core? (Given that you create a composer.json file with the repository information first.) The drupal-composer project is intended to be an all-in one solution, meaning that it includes drush, console, etc. If you just need core, you do not need the drupal-composer project.

Comment: Neograph is correct. drupal-composer, Acquia BLT, Docker4Drupal etc are all designed as accelerators to creating projects for Drupal 8 (which include the core), but contain a lot of tweaks and architectural changes to make it manageable in a modern environment (vs getting the tarball from drupal.org).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want drupal-console.  This tool can quickly create working Drupal 8 sites interactively or via command line. More info [here](https://drupalconsole.com/articles/how-to-download-and-install-drupal-8-using-drupal-console).

Another quick alternative is to use [DrupalVM](https://www.drupalvm.com/) and Varnish to spin up a fully working D8 site.  The DrupalVM defaults are to create a D8 sandbox site.

I believe that DrupalVM now has Docker support so you might be able to have a single VM and just spin up a new D8 box.